# Regarding the nomenclature of "natural" functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, arithmetic

I was wondering if there was a name associated with functions which purely involve the basic arithmetic operators including the derived operators like power etc. Basically,  functions which are not piece wise defined or involve the floor fucntion to name a few. Functions which are "natural" as to say.

Comment: I removed the tag 'functional analysis' as this pertains to an advanced branch of math, which studies a certain class of functions on infinite dimensional objects. I added the tag 'algebra-precalculus' because it's a large tag which is the correct level of study, and will bring in more attention to your question.

Comment: Are you including taking $n$th roots? If you are excluding them then the word you are looking for is probably "rational", or maybe even "polynomial" will do.

Comment: Yes, including roots, exponential. By the way, aren't rational functions simply the ratio of two real polynomials?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for "algebraic function".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function

Comment: Hmm... but it does not include the exponential function( a power x, where x is the variable). Thank you for your reply anyways.

Comment: Are you including trig functions?